# Erro no anúncio adbuddiz Android

Tags: android, anúncio

Na hora que chama o anúncio exibe esse erro e não mostra o anuncio

```
E/AdBuddiz: Can't show Ad: NETWORK_TOO_SLOW. Current network is too slow.
```

ele exibiu algumas vezes e agora aparece esse erro;

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro significa que o algoritmo detectou que sua conexão de internet esta muito lenta, certamente para exibir um vídeo em um tempo razoável.
Você esta utilizando rede 3G? Caso esteja, tentar repor os dados do aplicativo pode ajudar se o erro foi causado por um problema temporário na rede. 
Caso contrário, você precisa encontrar outra conexão de internet, de preferencia WiFi.
Mas mesmo se você não está vendo os anúncios por causa da conexão de internet lenta , seus usuários com internet mais rápida ainda poderão ver os anúncios.